# Foreach not working properly

Tags: c#, foreach, unity-container, infinite-loop

I'm trying to write a method that takes some  elements from Unity .config file. Each  element has type and mapTo attributes, and I'm taking their string values, getting substrings I need and putting them in two separated lists. After that I want to write the content of lists in some data grid.

The problem is that after a finishing all foreach loops code goes back into the one for checking single register and enters again in other two for types and mapTo values.
In other words in lists I get in-countless string values instead of only getting them once.
I'm a beginner and I've tried lot of things, but nothing seams to do a job. 
Anybody has an idea what I'm getting wrong?
The code of method in C# looks like this:

```
private void ReadAdvancedConfigFile(string path)
        {
            XElement root = null;
            root = XElement.Load(new XmlTextReader(path));

            if (root != null)
            {
                XNamespace ns = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/practices/2010/unity";
                var registers = root.Element(ns + "unity").Element(ns + "container").Descendants(ns + "register");

                if (registers.Count() > 0)
                {
                    var tipList = registers.Select(x => x.Attribute("type").Value);
                    var mapToList = registers.Select(x => x.Attribute("mapTo").Value);
                    List<string> listresult = new List<string>();
                    List<string> listresultm = new List<string>();

                    foreach (var reg in registers)
                    {
                        foreach (var tpl in tipList)
                        {
                            var end = tpl.IndexOf(',');
                            var start = tpl.LastIndexOf('.', (end == -1 ? tpl.Length - 1 : end)) + 1;
                            var result = tpl.Substring(start, (end == -1 ? tpl.Length : end) - start);
                            listresult.Add(result);
                        }
                        foreach (var mpl in mapToList)
                        {
                            var endm = mpl.IndexOf(',');
                            var startm = mpl.LastIndexOf('.', (endm == -1 ? mpl.Length - 1 : endm)) + 1;
                            var resultm = mpl.Substring(startm, (endm == -1 ? mpl.Length : endm) - startm);
                            listresultm.Add(resultm);
                        }

                        int maxLenList = Math.Max(listresult.Count, listresultm.Count);
                        for (int i = 0; i < maxLenList; i++)
                        {
                            if (i < listresult.Count && i < listresultm.Count)
                            {
                                _obsCollection.Add(new Tuple<string, string>(listresult[i], listresultm[i]));
                            }
                            else if (i >= listresult.Count)
                            {
                                _obsCollection.Add(new Tuple<string, string>(string.Empty, listresultm[i]));
                            }
                            else if (i >= listresultm.Count)
                            {
                                _obsCollection.Add(new Tuple<string, string>(listresultm[i], string.Empty));
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    tabela.ItemsSource = _obsCollection;
                }
            }
        }
```

Method gets call from a button named Load that finds Unity.config file from some location in file system like this:

```
 private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            OpenFileDialog fDialog = new OpenFileDialog();

            fDialog.Title = "Open XML file";
            fDialog.Filter = "XML files|*.config";
            fDialog.InitialDirectory = @"C:\";

            bool? control = fDialog.ShowDialog();
            if (control.Value)
            {
                var filePath = fDialog.FileName;
                ReadAdvancedConfigFile(filePath);
            }

        }
```

And in Unity.config is XML file with this format(I'm deleted most of  elements, to same some space here, it will work with this too):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>

    <configSections>
        <section name="unity" type="Microsoft.Practices.Unity.Configuration.UnityConfigurationSection, Microsoft.Practices.Unity.Configuration"/>
    </configSections>

    <unity xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/practices/2010/unity">

        <container name="container">

            <register name="configService" type="Web.Common.Interfaces.IConfigService, Web.Common"
                      mapTo="Web.Common.Services.ConfigServiceImpl, Web.Common">
                <lifetime type="singleton" />
                <constructor>
                    <param name="res" value="Resources.ClientStrings"> </param>
                    <param name="configFile" value="webclient.config"> </param>
                </constructor>
                <!--<property name="LocalisationService" dependencyName="LocalisationService" />-->
                <!--This is a property injection from the language plugin -->
            </register>

            <register name="scaleCoefConfigService" type="Web.WebClient.Services.IScaleCoefConfigService, Web.WebClient.TDMSWebApp"
                      mapTo="Web.WebClient.Services.Implementations.ScaleCoefConfigServiceImpl, Web.WebClient.TDMSWebApp">
                <lifetime type="singleton" />
                <constructor>
                    <param name="configService">
                        <dependency name="configService"/>
                    </param>
                </constructor>
            </register>

            <register name="sessionService" type="Web.Common.Interfaces.ISessionService, Web.Common" 
                      mapTo="Web.Common.Services.SessionServiceImpl, Web.Common">
                <lifetime type="singleton" />
            </register>

            <register name="licenseManagerService" type="Web.Common.Interfaces.ILicenseManagementService, Web.Common"
                      mapTo="Web.Common.Services.LicenseManagementServiceImpl, Web.Common">
                <lifetime type="singleton" />
            </register>
        </container>
    </unity>
</configuration>
```

Comment: We can't find bugs in your code when we can't even run it. Please, learn to debug your code : http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=C0vDKXIq_9A

Comment: As Euphoric says: narrow down your code. Create a demo project, remove all code that does not contribute to the problem and post it here.

Comment: I'm doing a debug and still can't realize whats wrong. Thanks anyway...I will continue to try :)

Comment: @PatrickHofman Ok, I will try to do that in next post. Hope I'm gonna be able to give you a nicer look into code. :)

Comment: Try it this time. How would you expect us to help you when we having nothing to go with?

Comment: @PatrickHofman I've edited post...Is this better?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I adjusted your code and now it works (removed `foreach`):

```
XElement root = null;
root = XElement.Load(new XmlTextReader(path));

if (root != null)
{
    XNamespace ns = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/practices/2010/unity";
    var registers = root.Element(ns + "unity").Element(ns + "container").Descendants(ns + "register");

    if (registers.Count() > 0)
    {
        var tipList = registers.Select(x => x.Attribute("type").Value);
        var mapToList = registers.Select(x => x.Attribute("mapTo").Value);
        List<string> listresult = new List<string>();
        List<string> listresultm = new List<string>();

        foreach (string tpl in tipList)
        {
            int end = tpl.IndexOf(',');
            int start = tpl.LastIndexOf('.', (end == -1 ? tpl.Length - 1 : end)) + 1;
            string result = tpl.Substring(start, (end == -1 ? tpl.Length : end) - start);
            listresult.Add(result);
        }

        foreach (string mpl in mapToList)
        {
            int endm = mpl.IndexOf(',');
            int startm = mpl.LastIndexOf('.', (endm == -1 ? mpl.Length - 1 : endm)) + 1;
            string resultm = mpl.Substring(startm, (endm == -1 ? mpl.Length : endm) - startm);
            listresultm.Add(resultm);
        }

        int maxLenList = Math.Max(listresult.Count, listresultm.Count);

        for (int i = 0; i < maxLenList; i++)
        {
            if (i < listresult.Count && i < listresultm.Count)
            {
                _obsCollection.Add(new Tuple<string, string>(listresult[i], listresultm[i]));
            }
            else if (i >= listresult.Count)
            {
                _obsCollection.Add(new Tuple<string, string>(string.Empty, listresultm[i]));
            }
            else if (i >= listresultm.Count)
            {
                _obsCollection.Add(new Tuple<string, string>(listresultm[i], string.Empty));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: yeah that totally worked, thanks :)
So I have one question. You changed almost all var to string and int types. Is there some catch with that? Like is there problem if we are using too much var for defining or something like that?
P.S. I have a new problem now, instead of getting those strings from list in datagrid I get some lines. But that's totally new problem :)

Comment: Sorry, I changed the `var` variables just for myself to make clear what was happening. I personally dislike `var`.

Comment: @nemo_87: Post an example in a new question and I will take a look.

Comment: Oh ok, I was thinking that maybe is not good using too much var. :)
I will new post it right now, I just need to study a code little bit better, so I can ask a right question. :)

Comment: I've posted new post and named it: Passing string values from list to datagrid
Gonna try to solve this problem, but if you get some idea thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 2):

Looks to me as if you don't need the foreach loop. You're already fetching all 'type' and 'mapTo' attributes when you query using LINQ:

```
var tipList = registers.Select(x => x.Attribute("type").Value);
var mapToList = registers.Select(x => x.Attribute("mapTo").Value);
```

This effectively gives you all the attributes of the xelements in 'registers'. 
You're not even using the var 'reg' within your loop...

Comment: Thanks for responding. I will try that right away and let you know did it worked :)

Comment: It does work when you remove `foreach (var reg in registers)`

Comment: @Reinder Tried to remove foreach(var reg in registers), but problem remains. I've totally messed up something real bad. :-/
But you were right, that loop didn't do anything, it was totally unnecessary. After exiting both two foreach loops it goes back to var tipList and var mapToList and copy values in lists again and again.